# .Net Dictionary Hashing for Object type keys

Tags: .net, object, dictionary, types, hash

I have a few questions regarding dictionary as below...

a> what algorithm is used to generate hash by the `Dictionary<T1,T2>` if `T1` is a reference or object type.

b> what collision avoiding techniques are used as part of that algorithm?

c> which of the following techniques are more useful to have a object class (`T1`) to be used as a key so that two different objects with same primitive type contents are assumed to be as the same key?

1. Overriding `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` call?
2. Implementing `IEquatable<T1>` interface?
3. `IEqualityComparer<T1>` interface?

d> when we use LINQ lambda function `.ToDictionary<>()` is it necessary that the  `IEnumerable` should be sorted on the field that is to be used as a key in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind ! I got my answer here....

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/4355bcf8-3f01-4a85-b05e-bb2e829009b6/

Thx guys.